# Getting HTTP transport error while executing google dataflow job

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am getting a constant error while executing a Dataflow job:

> BigQuery import job "dataflow_job_838656419" failed., : BigQuery creation of import job for table "TestTable" in dataset "TestDataSet" in project "TestProject" failed., : BigQuery execution failed., : HTTP transport error: Message: Invalid value for: String is not a valid value HTTP Code: 400

It does not give any specific reason for the google Dataflow job failing continuously.
How do I know what is the error I am committing while executing the google Dataflow job?

Comment: Can you provide the job ID please?

Comment: The job Id is 2016-08-29_10_19_38-10605284450672758855

Comment: Is the code using TableRow (https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/model/TableRow.html?is-external=true) and if so, does it use setF or set?

Comment: Yes the code uses TableRow object and uses set()

Comment: It looks like the job is specifying "String" as the type of a schema field. BigQuery documentation says it should be spelled out as "STRING". Could you try it this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is the incorrect use of the BigQuery API, which is case-sensitive with respect to field type.  Please specify "STRING" as the field type in the schema that you're providing.

Please see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables for more details.